# Getting the output from LAME and FLAC to show in bash dialog

Tags: linux, bash, dialog, mp3

I'm writing a .ogg and .flac to .mp3 converter in dialog (ncurses) and I wonder if it's possible to get the output from flac and ogg123 to be shown inside of dialog? Right now I have a good interface, but when the converting starts it just prints to terminal.

This is the flac2mp3 function right now:

```
   function ConvertFromFlac {
       old_IFS=$IFS             
       IFS=$'\n'                
       for line in `cat ./flacsongs`        
       do
           flac -cd "$line" | lame -h - "$line.mp3" 
       done
       IFS=$old_IFS                 
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way

```
ConvertFromFlac() {
    pipe=/tmp/$$.err
    mkfifo "$pipe"
    while IFS= read -r line ; do 
    do
        flac -cd "$line" 2>>"$pipe" | lame -h - "$line.mp3" 2>>"$pipe"
    done < ./flacsongs
}
```

And later if you want the output just read from `$pipe`. Don't forget to `rm` it when you're done.

Comment: Yes, the trick was to redirect output from both flac and lame. Now I just need to get dialog to present a textfile that is constantly changing to get the right effect.